Google Play Billing: "The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found" in Production
I am implementing subscriptions in my Android app using RevenueCat. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
1 Configured the Play Store and Google Cloud Console as per the RevenueCat documentation and tutorials.
2 Published the app to the Closed Testing track and enabled license testing.
3Verified that test users could successfully subscribe. The sandbox data section in RevenueCat reflects these successful tests.
After confirming that everything worked in the closed test, I:

Published the app to Production with a new APK.
Made sure the subscription products were published and active in the Play Console.

However, during Google’s review, they rejected the app stating that subscriptions could not be purchased. While subscription options are listed in the app, when attempting to purchase, the following error appears:
The item that you were attempting to purchase could not be found.
I’ve double-checked the following:

The subscription products are active and correctly configured in the Play Console.
The app is using the same product IDs as defined in the Play Console.
RevenueCat is properly linked to my Google account.

What could be causing this issue in the production environment when it works fine in closed testing?
Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!
